# How to stop local system service using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

How to stop service in local as well as remote system using vbscript? How to give system name in those scripts? How to stop service in multiple system by using single vb script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set objWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strServiceName = "MyService"
strOnServer = "\\ServerName"
intReturn = objwsh.Run("SC " & strOnServer & " Stop " & strServiceName, 0, True)
If (intReturn <> 0) Then MsgBox ("DID NOT successful stop " & strServiceName) Else MsgBox "Sucessfully stopped " & strServiceName
```

You have to get the service name from the properties in services.msc.

Comment: If i need to stop service in remote system , how to change the above  script?

Comment: If i need to stop service in multiple system, how to change the above script?

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of parameter used in above Run function?

Comment: Which parameter?  If you open a command prompt and type "sc /?" you should see everything you need.